# How to make the tooltip visible in a container that is overflow hidden using css?

Tags: css

i have a tooltip that shows when user hovers a button inside a dialog. these buttons are wrapped within ToolTip component and ToolTip component is within UsersContainer div.

below is my code,

```css
wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32px;
  width: 316px;
  min-height: 225px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

des_container {
  padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px;
  margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;
}

UsersContainer {
  padding: 14px;
  height: 104px;
  width: 316px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  &>div {
    margin: 2px;
  }
}

tooltip_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

inner_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}

tooltip_text {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="des_container">
    <span>title</span>
    <span>description</span>
  </div>
  <div class="UsersContainer">
    <div class="tooltip_wrapper">
      <div class="inner_wrapper">
        <div class="tooltip_text">
          <span>text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is tooltip is hidden behind the UsersContainer div as this UsersContainer div has overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: auto properties. when i remove these properties the tooltip is above the UsersContainer div for the first row of buttons and is no longer cropped.

[image]

can someone help me fix this? i have tried using position absolute on ToolTipWrapper div and this makes the tooltip appear above as expected but has the buttons in the UsersContainer div appear overlapped on one other.

i am not sure how to fix this. thanks.

Comment: Make a demo  in sandbox for this.

Comment: Your css is wrong. You need to use `.` to indicate a class selector.